# How to get bcm4360 work on kali linux live persistent USB?

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, persistence

I have a problem with "Kali Linux 2017.2"; I installed it on a USB with live persistence however I cannot connect it to the internet wirelessly for some reason I cannot seem to get it to find the wireless card (`bcm4360`)

I have tried many methods to try get it to work such as adding the stretch main contrib non-free to my source.List and downloading the headers, common and kbuild deb amd64 files to try and install them manually

Whenever I do `iwconfig` I receive `lo no wireless extensions`

I've also run

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But still no dice

`uname -a` : 
`Linux kali 4.12.0-kali1-amd64 #1 smp debian 4.12.6-1kali6 (2017-08-30) x86_64 gnu/linux`

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` : 
`broadcom limited bcm4360 802.11ac wireless network adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)`

In my sources list are :

```
Deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free 
Deb-src https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free 
Den http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

Comment: @GAD3R all done :)

Comment: @GAD3R when I run modprobe wl I receive "modprobe: error: ../libmod/libkmod-module.c: 832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='wl'" further goes on to say an error running install command for wl and finally could not insert 'wl': I operation not permitted

Comment: @GAD3R So I can't do anything?

Comment: @GAD3R i havent been able to figure out how to chroot into the live usb however, i reinstalled the os because something went wrong and it refused to boot, after installing everything i noticed that when i installed the broadcom package it installed wl into a 4.13.0 file path however, the error states it cannot find 4.12.0 as it doesnt exist, does that help at all ?

Comment: see this tuto  https://nathanpfry.com/how-to-customize-an-ubuntu-installation-disc/  to create a new iso including the missing package to enable `wl` module ,at the *Add packages to the system* you need the `broadcom-sta-dkms` and the `linux-headers` once  included you can get the wifi working